# Getting duplicates in dict

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary, say d1 that looks like this:

```
d = {'file1': 4098, 'file2': 4139, 'file3': 4098, 'file4': 1353, 'file5': 4139}
```

Now, I've figured out how to get it to tell me if there are any dublicates or not. But what I'd like to get it to do is tell me if there are any, and what 2 (or more) values (and corresponding keys) are dublicates.

The output for the above would tell me that file1 and file3 are identical and that file2 and file5 are identical

I've been trying to wrap my head around it for a few hours, and haven't found the right solution yet.

Comment: What code do you have so far that determines if there are duplicates?

Comment: if len(d) != len(set(d.values())):                                      
        print "Some files are identical"
else:                                                                
    print "No files are identical"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to get the duplicates:

```
[item for item in d.items() if [val for val in d.values()].count(item[1]) > 1]
```

that outputs:

> [('file3', 4098), ('file2', 4139), ('file1', 4098), ('file5', 4139)]

next sort the list by the second item in the tuple:

```
list = sorted(list, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

finally use `itertools.groupby()` to group by the second item:

```
list = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(list, operator.itemgetter(1))]
```

final output:

> [[('file3', 4098), ('file1', 4098)], [('file2', 4139), ('file5', 4139)]]

Comment: Thank you - That solves most of my problem. Would like each set of duplicates to be in their own list or tuble, but that should be solveable.

However, as the code seems to work, I can't really wrap my head around it and understand WHY it works. Guess that will come someday.

Comment: Thank you very much. Though I keep getting a
t = [t(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(t, operator.itemgetter(1))]

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Note: I opted for using "t" instead of "list" to comply with existing code.

Comment: @MadsRC Sorry for the late reply (I can only assume you solved this by now), but `list` is a function in that context not a variable.